# Rewrite URL parameter when using node.js and express without a redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am using node.js, express, and sockets.io to:

1. Find out whether or not the user has included a specific URL parameter when they arrive (working)
2. If not, make a new random room ID and join the user to that room (working)
3. Modify the address bar of the browser to reflect the new URL without redirecting the browser (unsure if possible, or how to accomplish)

First, I do not know if this is possible without violating DOM security. If it is, I would like to understand how I might be able to do it.

If it is not possible, and/or if I need to use a redirect, could you show me how to do it within my already working code within the working context of items #1 and #2?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var url = require('url');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  var roomID = req.query.me;
    if (roomID == null || !io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomID]) {
      console.log("URL room variable is: " + roomID);
      console.log('New room!');
      roomID = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 13);
      joinRoom(roomID);
      console.log("+ you just joined new room: " + roomID);
    } else {
      joinRoom(roomID);
      console.log("URL room variable is: " + roomID);
      console.log("= you just joined existing room: " + roomID);
    }
});

function joinRoom(roomID) {
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.join(roomID);
    io.sockets.in(roomID).emit('connectToRoom', "Joined room: http://localhost:3030/?me=" + roomID);
  });
  return;
}

server.listen(3030);
```

I do not have any sample code for the part that I'm trying to accomplish because I simply don't know where I should begin. So I would appreciate any direction (redirection? pun intended).

Thank you!

Comment: You can't change what is displayed in the browser URL bar purely from the server without a redirect.  The browser requests URL X and then displays X in the URL bar.  You can change what is displayed in the URL bar from client-side Javascript.  So, you could add some JS to the page that would then change what is shown in the URL bar as the page loads.  This question seems a bit like the XY Problem where you're asking about issues with your chosen solution rather than describing the original problem and letting us come up with possible solutions for you.

Comment: @jfriend00: I don't mean to put the cart before the horse. If I'm thinking incorrectly about the problem and my code shows that incorrect thinking, I'm open to updating... I think the answer is in redirects... But I haven't found a good way to accomplish it for what I want to do.

Comment: Well.  Why do you have to change the URL?  Can the room state just be stored in a cookie?  If you want it in the URL, then why don't you just join the room and redirect and let the redirected URL with the room already in it, then handle the rest of the request?

Comment: Also, your `joinRoom()` function will not work properly.  You will be adding a new `io.on('connection', ...)` handler for every single page that is request.  They will pile up and soon you will have thousands of those handlers that will all fire for every single new socket.io connection.  You will need a different design for that.  Again, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish so I''m not what to recommend.

Comment: I think your recommendation for updating what is displayed in the address bar from the client side is the best approach. I'll have to look into how the `joinRoom()' function is operating. Thank you for pointing out that problem!